# Ionic return key on iOS keyboard doesn't work

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have the following in my HTML file:

```
<ion-view view-title="" name="login-view">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <i class="icon ion-email placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Username"   ng-model="data.username">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <i class="icon ion-key placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"   ng-model="data.password">
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

So when I am filling the username and hit return key on iOS keyboard I am supposed to go to the next field (password), but simply nothing happens. Any ideas ?